# Need to combine multiple rows based on index

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with values like

```
     0    1      2
a    5   NaN     6
a    NaN  2     NaN
```

Need the output by combining the two rows based on index 'a' which is same in both rows

Also need to add multiple columns and output as single column

Need the output as below. Value 13 since adding 5 2 6

```
     0
a   13
```

Trying this using concat function but getting errors

Comment: Try `df.groupby(df.index).sum().sum(1)`

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Pandas dataframe.sum()` ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"0":[5, np.NaN], "1":[np.NaN, 2], "2":[6,np.NaN]})
row_total = data.sum(axis = 1, skipna = True)
row_total.sum(axis = 0)
```

result:

```
13.0
```

**EDIT:** @Chris comment (did not see it while writing my answer) shows how to do it in one line, if all rows have same index.

data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"0":[5, np.NaN], 
                     "1":[np.NaN, 2], 
                     "2":[6,np.NaN]},
                     index=['a', 'a'])
```

gives:

```
    0   1   2
a   5.0 NaN 6.0
a   NaN 2.0 NaN
```

Then

```
data.groupby(data.index).sum().sum(1)
```

Returns

```
13.0
```